# how to position a div of grid_6 to the far right inside a div grid_24

Tags: html, css

How can i position the div spotlight-grey to the far right inside the div spotlight?

```
<section class="banner">
    <div class="container_24">
        <div class="grid_24">
            <div class="spotlight">
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="spotlight-grey">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Updated:CSS**

```
div .spotlight {
    width:100%;
    height:390px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}
.spotlight-grey {
    width:100%;
    height:390px;
    background-color:rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.8);
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.spotlight-grey{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
.spotlight{
    position: relative;
}
```

---

OR:

```
.spotlight-grey{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: this is my css and with position:absolute the div is spanning to the full width instead of keeping the grid_6 and position itself on the right of parent div                                                      .spotlight{
 width:100%;
 height:390px;
 background-color:blue;
 position:relative;
}
.spotlight-grey{
 width:100%;
 height:390px;
 background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.8);
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
}

Comment: @Josef - Without a demonstration it's hard to get the whole picture you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="banner">
    <div class="container_24">
        <div class="grid_24">
            <div class="spotlight">
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <div class="spotlight-grey"> Hi</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.spotlight-grey {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width:20px;
        border:1px solid black;
}
.spotlight {
    position: relative;
}
.grid_24
{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga8kJ/2/)**

## [Updated Fiddle of your CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga8kJ/6/)

Comment: should i style the .grid_24? i changed the width of .spotlight-grey from 100% to 200px and it worked.The problem is that i prefer to use the width 100%

Comment: see width 100% expands to the whole page.. if you want to fix the div in a particular place give it in pixels